# Using "Contingency" to express busy time

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Can we use `contingency` to express we are busy with something? Is it common?

Like for example:

> I have a few contingencies but I'll be free in a month.

Comment: Usually **commitment(s)** is used to express being busy. You could say "I will have a busy month **contingent** on whether we can get our funding," but it means your busy-ness is conditional on *something else*

Comment: I think to express *exactly* what you mean there you should probably say *I have a few **issues arising** but I'll be free in a month*. This would make it clear that the things you need to deal with (this month) weren't known about until a short time ago (they're ***unforeseen*** "contingencies").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use contingency for something that you know you will be busy with.

A contingency is some thing that may happen, or may not. So it's not so much "I will be busy" as "I might be busy".

You might say

> I am definitely busy for the next three weeks: allowing for contingencies, let's say a month. I should be free after that.